# build phalcon old version for php 7.0 on macos

Tags: macos, mamp, phalcon, php-7.0

It was necessary to take in the development of the old project:

> PHP Version 7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
>
> phalcon Version   3.0.3
>
> Build Date    May 31 2017 14:42:03
>
> Powered by Zephir Version 0.9.5a-dev

I tryed build phalcon 3.0 in local env for MAMP 5.1

Mamp has php 7.0.13 - its ok - will do

beagin:

> mkdir /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/include

...

and donwload sources php 7.0.13 &unzip 
...

> cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/include/php/ext/
>
> clone git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
>
> cd cphalcon/
>
> git fetch
>
> git checkout 3.0.x
>
> git pull ( maybe =) )
>
> ../../../../../../../bin/phpize
>
> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/bin/phpize
>
> cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/include/php/ext/cphalcon/build/php7/64bits
>
> ./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/bin/php-config
>
> make test
>
> sudo make install clean

done, restart, clean, check phpinfo ... and he showed me: phalcon Version   3.4.1 !!! 
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/bin/php -i    - 3.4.1 !!!

and trys next way by manual (in install.sh)  install ...

> cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/include/php/ext/cphalcon/build/
>
> sudo ./install --phpize /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/bin/phpize --php-config /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/bin/php-config

result:

> Build complete.
>   Don't forget to run 'make test'.
>
> Installing shared extensions:     /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/
>   Installing header files:          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/include/php/
>
> Thanks for compiling Phalcon!
>   Build succeed: Please restart your web server to complete the installation

added ext...=phalcon.so in php.ini  and in mamp conf to.

check /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.31/bin/php -i
Version 3.4.1
Build Date  Sep 25 2018 16:32:49
Powered by Zephir   Version 0.10.10-d1b4cc68d9
in mamp after restart to same version

Phalcon builded 3.4 for php 7.0.13 ....  in branch 3.0.x

What am I doing wrong?
how do I build an older version?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install from Phalcon's repository in Packagecloud ( follow their installation instructions): https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable?page=211